# Call an abstract class in asynctask in android

Tags: android, abstract-class, toast

I am trying to use my custom `Toast` in `AsyncTask`, unfortunately I cannot use that directly so I searched over here. I read some post about creating an abstract class where I can put the method for my custom toast. But I am having a problem on calling it in the `onPostexecute()` of my `AsyncTask`.

> ToastClass.java

```
public class ToastClass extends Activity
{
     public void ViewToast(String toast_msg){

          Typeface tfR= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Gothic_Regular.TTF");
          LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
          View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_bg, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toastAttribute));
          TextView msg = ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.txt_toast));
          msg.setTypeface(tfR);
          msg.setText(toast_msg);
          msg.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,16);
          Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
          mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
          mytoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
          mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          mytoast.show();

     }
}
```

> ToastActivity.java

```
public abstract class ToastActivity extends Activity{

     protected void ViewToast(String toast_msg){

         Typeface tfR= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Gothic_Regular.TTF");
         LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
         View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_bg, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toastAttribute));
         TextView msg = ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.txt_toast));
         msg.setTypeface(tfR);
         msg.setText(toast_msg);
         msg.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,16);
         Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
         mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
         mytoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
         mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         mytoast.show();

     }
}
```

And I'm calling that this way

```
ToastClass toast = new ToastClass();
toast.ViewToast(msg);
```

Can you teach me the right thing to do?

Comment: Where do you use `ToastActivity`?

Comment: i am trying to do this " create methods inside anonymous classes, but you can only call these methods inside of the anonymous class" but it seems I'm so wrong, I did not make it that way, did I?